# Accessing host file system on all nodes in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I have a requirement where i dump some data under /etc on all the nodes within my cluster and i have a statefulSet deployed on this cluster with 1 instance on every node. I wanted to understand how can i access data residing at /etc on all the nodes in the cluster from within my POD during runtime when the request hits my POD via the service ?

e.x: 3 node cluster (N1, N2 and N3). Each node has the stateful set deployed. Lets call it N1pod, N2pod and N3pod. If a request hits N2pod, i want the data from N1 and N3 apart from N2 from /etc/foo.txt.

Comment: Did a `volume` of type `hostPath` not do that for you? What do you mean by "N1 and N3 apart"?

Comment: @Matthew L Daniel: Mounting the volume of hostPath will only help me fetch data from /etc by the POD on the same node where the request ended up. I want to fetch the data from /etc on other nodes as well.

Comment: @Raks, use nfs volume mapping.

Comment: @Dhananjay: I do not want to pre-establish the mount paths from all other nodes in my yaml file. I was thinking of using SSH by making my container a privilaged one. But just wanted to know if there is any other k8s construct that would help me achieve what i want during runtime.